# The type or namespace name 'Bussen' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Tags: c#, forms, types, namespaces, csc

When i try to compile my source code it gived me this error. When i run the program form visual studio it works. I am currently creating a windows form card game for me and my friends. This is my main Program.cs file.

### Error:

> Program.cs(16,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Bussen'
>   could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly
>   reference?)

### Code:

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using bussen;

namespace bussen
{
    static class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// The main entry point for the application.
        /// </summary>
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()
        {
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Bussen());
        }
    }
}
```

The other file is called forms1.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using bussen;


namespace bussen
{
    public partial class Bussen : Form
    {

        public List<string> allCards = new List<string> { };
        public List<string> CardsColour = new List<string> { };

        public Bussen()
        {

            FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized;
            InitializeComponent();

            LoadCards();
        }

        private void SelectCard(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Random rnd = new Random();
            int RandomNumber = rnd.Next(0, allCards.Count);
            try
            {
                if (CardsColour.IndexOf(allCards[RandomNumber]) < 26)
                {
                    (sender as Button).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Black;
                }
                else
                {
                    (sender as Button).ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
                }
                (sender as Button).Text = allCards[RandomNumber];
                allCards.Remove(allCards[RandomNumber]);
            }
            catch
            {
                LoadCards();
            }
        }

        public void LoadCards()
        {
            StreamReader streamreader = new StreamReader(@"cards.txt");
            string line;
            while ((line = streamreader.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                allCards.Add(line);
                if (CardsColour.Count < 52)
                {
                    CardsColour.Add(line);
                }
            }
            streamreader.Close();
        }

        private void Restart(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Restart();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: "When i try to compile my source code it gived me this error. When i run the program form visual studio it works." - since lots of people use visual studio to compile their C# programs and that's apparently not what you're doing (since you're saying something is different between compiling and running in visual studio), how *are* you compiling the code when you get an error?

Comment: Namespace names should start with a capital letter. You don't need to `using Bussen` in a file that has `namespace Bussen` in it

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I use the command [csc "Program.cs"] in windows powershell. I dont know another way to do this.

Comment: @CaiusJard If i change my namespace to Bussen and my class to BussenClass(Otherwise it says (error CS0118: 'Bussen' is a namespace but is used like a type)). It wil still give me this error. Program.cs(16,33): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BussenClass' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?).

Comment: You're allowed (and expected) to provide *more than one* file name when compiling at the command line using `csc`.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thank you very much. This was the problem :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I should have provided more than one file name when compiling
-it was [scs "program.cs"]
-but is should have been [csc "program.cs" "Form1.cs" "Form1.Designer.cs"]